# Typescript how to test if regex is valid without getting syntax error

Tags: node.js, regex, typescript

I have some code that loads a number of regular expressions from an external source. I would like to test whether a given string is regular regex without crashing the application with a syntax error. I tried using try/catch blocks, but it appears that recent versions of Node will throw a syntax error when trying to parse an invalid expression as a regular expression and I see no way of recovering from a syntax error?

Here is a quick example:

```
try {
  new RegExp(/?/);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

When running this on Node.js or directly in the browser console the catch block will never be resolved, the script just fails.

Comment: *"When running this on Node.js or directly in the browser console the catch block will never be resolved"* - Yes, because you're getting a compile-time error with this code. `new RegExp()` expects a *string*, not a regular expression literal. If you write an invalid regex literal there, that's exactly the same type of error as not closing a string properly, or forgetting a bracket. Those cannot be resolved with try/catch, either.

Comment: Right. My inputs will be strings, so it was a mistake in my little proof of concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are creating a RegExp from a regular expression literal.  The compiler is likely catching the illegal expression, so its not even getting as far as a runtime exception.

In your explanation, you say that you are loading regex strings from an external source, and so it seems these would more likely be strings containing a regular expression.  In this case, the regular expression will be evaluated at runtime, and you should be able to catch an exception.

In the below snippet, you can see that the RegExp is being created from a string (observe the quotes).

**Edit**

Note that when creating from string, you don't need the prefix and suffix `/`, those are used to denote a regular expression literal.

Now, the exception is thrown when creating the RegExp, "Invalid regular expression: nothing to repeat".

```js
let r = undefined;
try {
    r = new RegExp('?');
    console.log(r.test('abc'));
}
catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error.message);
}
```

Comment: When creating regex from string in JavaScript, don't include the enclosing slashes `/`.

Comment: Right. Of course the inputs are strings. I just tried the above. Using `new RegExp('/?/')` as input it does not actually throw an error. But if I do something like `new RegExp('/[/')` it does throw an error, so I suppose that covers my need.

Comment: @zkwsk As I said, you need to remove the `/`, otherwise the regex will not match want you want.

Comment: Ok. With the `/` removed it will catch `?`. `new RegExp('?')` throws `Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to repeat`.

Comment: @zkwsk That's the expected result. That's the exact same exception you get at compile time when you try to use `/?/` (which is an invalid regex). But now you can `catch` it at runtime without your code crashing. `/?/` and `new RegExp('?')` are the same thing - they represent the same invalid regular expression.